# Redigo: getting errors on apache load testing

Tags: go, benchmarking, redigo

I am connecting my `go` program to `redis` using library `redigo`. When i run one request I get correct results. But on load testing, using apache benchmark tool, It works when:

```
ab -n 1000 -k -c 10 -p post.txt -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://localhost:8084/abcd
```

However when request is:

```
ab -n 1000 -k -c 15 -p post.txt -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://localhost:8084/abcd
```

I am getting error:

```
panic: dial tcp :6379: too many open files
```

This is my code:

```
func newPool() *redis.Pool {
    return &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle: 80, // max number of connections
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            return c, err
        },
        // If Wait is true and the pool is at the MaxActive limit, then Get() waits
        // for a connection to be returned to the pool before returning
        Wait: true,
    }
}

var pool = newPool()

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func func1(pool *redis.Pool, id int) string {
    c := pool.Get()
    defer c.Close()
    m, err := redis.String(c.Do("HGET", "key", id))
    checkError(err)
    return m
}

func func2(pool *redis.Pool, string_ids []string) chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    var ids []int
    var temp int
    for _, v := range string_ids {
        temp, _ = strconv.Atoi(v)
        ids = append(ids, temp)
    }
    go func() {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(len(ids))
        for _, v := range ids {
            go func(id int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                c <- func1(pool, id)
            }(v)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()
    return c
}
func getReq(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := req.ParseForm()
    checkError(err)
    ids := req.Form["ids[]"]
    for v := range func2(pool, ids) {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/abcd", getReq)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8084", nil))
}
```

How to handle atleast 40 concurrent request using apache benchmark tool.

**Note**: I haven't changed anything in my redis conf file

I am getting following response when running apache benchmark tool. Only 15 request are completed.

```
$ ab -n 1000 -k -c 15 -p post.txt -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://localhost:8084/abcd
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)
Total of 15 requests completed
```

Comment: That's not and error you're showing, it's just a part of the stack trace. Please show the error output, or the entire stack trace.

Comment: @JimB I have updated the question. Also the stack trace is too large. I have added the last lines.

Comment: Those are just goroutine stacks, and have nothing to do with the error. The cause of the stack trace it printed first, along with the panicking goroutine.

Comment: I got it now. The error is `panic: dial tcp :6379: too many open files`. How to solve this?

Comment: Seems self explanatory, you either increase the ulimit to allow more open files, or don't run so many requests concurrently.

Comment: Also, that error isn't fatal to your program, dont panic on regular errors.

Comment: yes, I should have framed the question correctly!

Comment: Use [pipelines](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#hdr-Pipelining) instead of goroutines when optimizing calls to Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue immediately, set `MaxActive` on your `redis.Pool`, which you mention in the comments but don't set yourself.

Fundamentally though, you should not be dispatching goroutines for every `id` lookup. Your maximum possible concurrency would then be `(number of client connections) x (number of ids in the request)`, each of which can open a new redis connection. It would be far faster and more efficient to have a single redis connection read each of the `ids` serially. There's no need for any of the extra concurrency you have here, do it all serially from the handler, and don't convert the strings to ints when redis only operates on string keys to begin with.

```
func getReq(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := req.ParseForm()
    checkError(err)

    c := pool.Get()
    defer c.Close()

    for _, id := range req.Form["ids[]"] {
        m, err := redis.String(c.Do("HGET", "key", id))
        checkError(err)
        fmt.Println(id)
    }
}
```

If you want to optimize this further, you can use [pipelines](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#hdr-Pipelining) to reduce the round trips to the redis server.

```
for _, id := range req.Form["ids[]"] {
    c.Send("HGET", "key", id))
}
c.Flush()
values, err := redis.Strings(c.Receive())
checkError(err)
...
```

Comment: ids which I am receiving through post request are about 80-100. Should I still connect to redis serially? I think that will decrease the performance. Also you said about using pipeline, Will you please give an example of how can i use it in my code?

Comment: @Jagrati: yes, query all the ids over 1 connection, opening 1500 concurrent connections only increases contention on the database and will degrade performance significantly.